using the current locale/language in a Tcl/Tk application on macOS
We are building an application in Tcl/Tk.
Because of our international user base, we implemented i18n/l10n using gettext, which works nicely.
Mostly.
On macOS, some of the menu items are provided by the system (e.g. Quit), but this never gets translated (even though we do provide a translation for Quit in our .po/.msg files).
This affects:

common menu enties (Quit, Preferences, Minimize (the current window),...
buttons in a tk_messageBox -type yesnocancel,...
...

I understand that our local translations do not apply to system provided strings.
However, the OS actually does know how to provide translated strings for these. It just doesn't apply them.
Why?
maybe related: in macOS, I can configure (via the system preferences) a given Application to run under a language different from the default. However, with our Application this option is disabled and macOS tells me, that our application ...

doesn't support additional languages.


(EDIT it turns out that the last paragraph was indeed unrelated)

Tk uses the system UI stuff there. If it is doing something (or failing to do something) to enable picking up the system locale for those elements, that's probably a bug.

OTOH, I can't check in a useful way. No development tools for that platform right now, nor any experience with where such things may be triggered.

in the meantime i figured out the 2nd part ("support additional languages in the System Preferences"), but unfortunately this was not related... so i think i'm going to remove that part of my Q.
